# how to disable a button on restart of an activity android

Tags: android

I have activity flow
Activity 1-> Activity 2->Activity 3

If the user performs certain action in Activity 3, shared preferences boolean variable "performed" stores true. Now if the user presses back button to load Activity 2, it doesn't (i used finish()) and loads Activity 1. This is fine and as per the need.

What I want now is, when Activity 1 restarts this way, based on the value of the shared preferences boolean variable "performed" value true the button in Activity should be hidden.

I am using,

```
if (preferences.getBoolean("performed",false)){  
    button.setVisibility(View.Gone);  
}
```

I have written this code in onRestart method of the Activity 1.

What am I missing?

The button does not hides.

Comment: use onResume() method

Comment: in your way the activity not `restart`. The activity start as new activity,so use your if condition in `onresume`.

Answer (score -1):

I have done it in following way 
 - wrote a singalton class has variable IsVisited.
 - check if it is visited in onResume() method
 - if visited then set visibility of the button gone

> Main Activity

```
Controller c;
Button bu ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     bu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    c = Controller.getController();
    bu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            c.setIsVisited(true);
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, mainactivity2.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(c.getIsVisited())
    {
        bu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

> Another Activity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    Controller c = Controller.getController();
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });


}
```

> Controller Class (Singleton Class)

```
public class Controller {

private static final Controller controller = new Controller();
private Boolean isVisited = false;

private Controller()
{

}
public static Controller getController()
{
    return controller;
}

public Boolean getIsVisited() {
    return isVisited;
}

public void setIsVisited(Boolean isVisited) {
    this.isVisited = isVisited;
}}


![enter image description here][1]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have no guarantee that the Controller instance will remain in memory, as if your application goes to background for whatever reason, it can be killed and gced.

Comment: Yes , If application is Closed then Controller object will get destroyed . if you want to show some thing for only for first time then can go for shared preferences or file's

Comment: Hi Down Woter Please Give Reason for down wote. So i will correct My mistake.